# How to turn off images in w3m

Tags: linux, command-line, w3m

I would like to know how to turn OFF images in w3m.  I installed w3m images so that i could view images in the cli program ranger.  But I would prefer to turn this off for w3m.

I would have thought that there would be some option in .w3m/config but I am finding it very difficult to find good documentation on this.

Is there anyone that can help me?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

you can add this macro in your keymap file **$EDITOR ~/.w3m/keymap**

```
keymap  \\\i    COMMAND "SET_OPTION display_image=toggle ; RELOAD"        # toggle image display
```

then press **\i** to toggle images on or off